# Banner from Admob doesn't show

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I read a some sites and tutorial how to implement Admob properly in Android.
Despite this Admob doesn't show in my application.

Below I show implementation of BANNER:

**Manifest:**

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

**Java.class:**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
--------------------------------------------------
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**Layout.xml:**

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Dependencies:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
```

I use the same code in 4-5 activities. 
I use original Unit_id. 
In android studio banner style shows but in real device and emulator it doesn't.

Could somebody help me to resolve this situation?

Comment: How long did you wait for the banner ad to load? I notice in my own apps, here is often a delay between starting my app and loading the ad.

Comment: p.s. It's not a good idea to post your MobAd ID here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you for your info but I changed the number of Unit_Id for this post :) I had a beta version of app one week ago and today I entered my correct unit_id to update for Google Play as an official version of app.

Comment: @gryzek please share logs. filter with Ads. logs usually gives error code or exception for not loading ads

Comment: also i hope you have given permissions to read internet etc

Comment: Problem resolved. AdMob delayed showing advertisments. It took a time but now it works :) Thank you for help.